# How to grab larger csv files from AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, amazon-s3, dask

I am trying to go through all the csv files I have an AWS S3 bucket to grab all the data in these csv files and put them into a dataframe. The code I provided first grabs all the csv file names then grabs each individual file and runs it through `csv.reader` to grab the data and then puts them into a list, which then creates a dataframe from it. My issue is that the code skips over files larger than 100 KB, with some of my files being larger than 300 KB. I am trying to grab every single file that has KB of data to then put into a dataframe.

This is my code:

```
# Set the S3 bucket and directory path where CSV files are stored
aws_access_key_id ='XXXXXXXXXX'
aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
s3_bucket_name = 'arcodp'
folder_name = 'lab_data/'


# Get a list of all CSV files in the S3 bucket directory
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)



paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name)



csv_files = [obj['Key'] for page in pages for obj in page['Contents'] if obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')]


# Create an empty list to store the dataframes
df_list = []
ARCID_lst =  []
# Read each CSV file into a dataframe and append it to the df_list
for file in csv_files:
    try: 
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=file)
        data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
    
        # Read the CSV file line by line and append each line to a list
        rows_list = []
        csv_reader = csv.reader(data.splitlines(), delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        for row in csv_reader:
            rows_list.append(row)

        df_list.extend(rows_list)
    except:
        ARCID_no_hit = file.split('/')[1].split('_')[0]
        ARCID_lst.append(ARCID_no_hit)

# Convert the list of rows into a pandas dataframe
df_par = pd.DataFrame(df_list)

    # Print the first 5 rows of the combined dataframe
df_par[0:10]
```

Is there an keyword argument for `csv.reader` in order to read bigger files? I have not found anything online that satisfies this argument. I also tried using `dask` but using this code I only get `No such file or directory: '/user/user/documents/extract_data/"1000231"|"None"|"20221130".` The files aren't on my local computer so not sure why this would occur. Here is the code for ```dask``:

```
# Set the S3 bucket and directory path where CSV files are stored
aws_access_key_id ='XXXXXXXXXXXXX'
aws_secret_access_key='XXXXXXXXXX'
s3_bucket_name = 'arcodp'
folder_name = 'lab_data/'


# Get a list of all CSV files in the S3 bucket directory
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)



paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name)



csv_files = [obj['Key'] for page in pages for obj in page['Contents'] if obj['Key'].endswith('.csv')]

# Create an empty list to store the dataframes

df_list = []
ARCID_lst =  []
for file in csv_files:
    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket_name, Key=file)
        data = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        
        # Create a delayed Dask dataframe for each CSV file
        df = delayed(dd.read_csv)(data, sep='|', header=None, blocksize=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, engine='c')
        df_list.append(df)
    except:
        ARCID_no_hit = file.split('/')[1].split('_')[0]
        ARCID_lst.append(ARCID_no_hit)

# Combine all delayed Dask dataframes into a single Dask dataframe
df_combined = dd.from_delayed(df_list)

# Compute the final pandas dataframe
df_par = df_combined.compute()

# Print the first 5 rows of the combined dataframe
df_par.head()
```

Comment: How does the code skip over files larger than 100 KB?

Comment: Please do provide what you tried with dask, else remove that part of your question as we cannot help you with the information given.

Comment: @Jarmod I am not sure how it skips over but when I look at the dataframe, the ARCID's thave over 100KB do not show up

Comment: @mdurant I have added my code using ```dark```

Comment: Any chance they are not actually present in the S3 bucket or they do not have a suffix that exactly matches ".csv" (case-sensitive)?

Comment: @jarmod they are present in the S3 bucket, and for example here are two files that it has not captured ARC1001773457_2023221.csv this one being 300.4 KB, and ARC1012424002_202328.csv being 137.3 KB with the right suffix

Comment: You're catching all possible exceptions, if you log the exception error messages, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to do this using dask

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv("s3://{s3_bucket_name}/{folder_name}/*.csv", 
    storage_options=dict(key='XXXXXXXXXXXXX', secret='XXXXXXXXXX',
    sep='|', ...)
```

and that's it.

Comment: will this code do it for every single csv file and put them all into a dataframe?

Comment: That is exactly what it does.